# how to get the title, description, pictures on the page?

Tags: page-template, media-library

I created a template, but it does not output anything

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery
*/

get_header(); 


?>
<section>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

                 $args = array(
                   'post_type' => 'attachment',
                   'numberposts' => -1,
                   'post_status' => null,
                   'post_parent' => $post->ID
                  );

                  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                     if ( $attachments ) {
                        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                           echo '<li>';
                           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                           echo '<p>';
                           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
                           echo '</p></li>';
                          }
                     }

                 endwhile; endif; ?>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Before you can access $post in the loop, you need to declare it with `global $post;`.  But since you're in the loop, you might want to use `get_the_id()` to access the post ID.  Also, I'm assuming that you've applied this template to a post or page - the template itself won't display anything.

Comment: did you call your template with `get_template_part` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the same thing with `get_children`. It will  get you.  Here is an sample code for you.

```
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                   echo $attachment->post_title; 

                    echo $attachment->post_content; 

        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' )  ? wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' ) :   wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

        echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current">';
      }
    }
```

I am not sure about the problem in your code.  But it will get you result.